# How to automatically detect a function and return a value

Tags: javascript, ruby, function

I am trying to build a system in javascript as ruby.

For example, when I define a function a, how can call `a`(not `a()`) and get `1`?

```
var a = function(){
  return 1;
}
console.log(a);//wanted result 1, not function(){...}
console.log(a());//it's okay.
```

I think it can be possible using `macro` so that before runnning, detect `a` as function and automatically change to `a()`, But I haven't got any idea, how can I do it.
Please help me.
UPDATE: I found a function detecting a function type variable but I don't have any idea how can use it.

```
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
 var getType = {};
 return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "a system in javascript as ruby".

Comment: I want to use `a` not `a()` to get 1, @Rajesh's answer is similar

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds like you want to change the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a get property of an object to achieve this:

```js
function getValue(str) {
  return 'Hello ' + str;
}

function Person(fname, lname){
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
    get: function(){
      return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname
    }
  });
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'greet', {
    get: function(){
      return getValue(this.fullName)
    }
  });
}

var p = new Person('foo', 'bar');
console.log(p.greet)
```

Comment: Great! I have found really exciting thing from you.

Comment: Note, these values(*`greet`, `fullName`*) do have a setter, so doing `p.fullName = 'bla'` will not do anything. You can also use this to achieve immutability.

Comment: I see, Thanks really.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression to do this. You wrap the function parentheses and then add a set of `()` to the end. Whenever you call `a` the function inside it will fire immediately.

```
 var a = (function(){
 return 1;
 })();
 console.log(a)
 // will return 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, `console.log(a)` will return 1 but `console.log(a())` will return what?

Comment: sorry, I must have misunderstood what you were trying to do. I thought that you wanted to call `a` instead of `a()`. In my example, a is not a function, it is just the value of what the internal iife returns.

Comment: I am trying to a, and a() both possible